# Increment a value based on return value

Tags: java

I've the below Java code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.println("row count is " + j);
            increment(j);
            j += 1;
        }
    }

    private static int increment(int j) {
        if (j == 2) {
            j += 1;
            System.out.println("row count is " + j);
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

Here I want to increment the `j` value based on the return value.

The current output I'm getting is.

```
row count is 0
row count is 1
row count is 2
row count is 3
row count is 3
row count is 4
```

My expected output is

```
row count is 0
row count is 1
row count is 2
row count is 3
row count is 4
row count is 5
```

Here I'm aware that putting

```
if (j == 2) {
    j += 1;
    System.out.println("row count is " + j);
}
```

in my `for` block solves the problem, but this is a like a replica of my main code which in in the form of my input provided. And I've to follow this pattern, i mean increment the value by checking for the condition in my method.

please let me know how can i get this.

Thanks

Comment: you actually need to assign the return value of `increment` to `j`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java works with `Pass-By-Value`, you can´t just change the parameter `j` in your method `increment` to change the original value in your `main`.

you need to call increment and store the return value into `j` again.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5;
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.println("row count is " + j);
        j = increment(j); //  IT is important to store it in `j` again, otherwise j will still be 2 after the execution
        j += 1;
    }
}

private static int increment(int j) {
    if (j == 2) {
        j += 1;
        System.out.println("row count is " + j);
    }
    return j;
}
```

If you want to understand why this was the case i´d recomend to go through [this So question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

The `j` in your `increment` function is a copy of the `j` in your loop (i.e. it's not the same "object", moreover it's a primitive), therefore if you modify `j` in the function, it does not get updated outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the returned value to something, you first need to have it.

Either do something like:

```
if ( increment(j) == expectedValue)
```

or do:

```
int test = increment(j);
if( test == expectedValue)
```